# Extracting HTML Table with HTML String - Python / Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a table tag saved as a string in a list.

The string is saved as follows

'''/table .. lots of random html .. /table>

I essentially want to take this string, search the parsed html file, find the table extract it and move it to a dataframe. I am struggling with matching the string and extracting the table.

My code is as follows - thanks so much guys

```
        url = XXX
        table_tags = df['table_tags'][0]
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        table_tag = table_tags[0]
        x = soup.findAll('table',table_tag)
```

Comment: is the `table_tag` is text value are you searching?

Comment: @KunduK Yes, the table_tag variable is the string of the html table tag. That is what I am trying to search. End goal is to match the string, extract that table to a DF. Ty

Comment: I appreciate if you post an example for better solution?

Comment: @KunduK I ran it with regular expression and the return value for x is an element.ResultSet with a size of 0. Do you know if its possible to covert the string just directly into a tag?

Comment: If you could post some example it would be better to provide right solution?

Answer (score 0):

If it is text to verify the table then use regular expression `re.`

```
import re

url = XXX
table_tags = df['table_tags'][0]
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
table_tag =''.join(table_tags[0])
x = soup.findAll('table',text=re.compile(table_tag))
```